# G++ compiler not recognizing SQLAPI.h header file

Tags: c++, g++, sqlapi++

I'm trying to compile a C++ program on my MacBook CLI using:

```
g++ -o -I/Users/user/SQLAPI/include/SQLAPI.h program driver.cpp
```

but getting the error:

```
driver.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'SQLAPI.h' file not found
#include <SQLAPI.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I placed the download from https://www.sqlapi.com/Download/ into directory /Users/user/SQLAPI/. I've confirmed that the SQLAPI.h file is in /Users/user/SQLAPI/include/SQLAPI.h, so I'm confused as to why my g++ isn't recognizing the header file. Please help!

Comment: The `-I` is the name of the ***directory***, not the actual header file. See g++'s documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for `-I` is *the directory* to search for the headers.

The argument for `-o` is the output file name.

You most probably want to:

```
g++ -I /Users/user/SQLAPI/include -o program driver.cpp
```

Which of course most probably will solve only the current include problem and will not link with SQLAPI library.

Comment: I tried with -I/Users/user/SQLAPI/include actually, but interestingly it didn't work when I placed the -I flag after the -o flag. After swapping those two, the compilation worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @park-junha The name of the output file must follow `-o ` immediately. If you put `-I` after it there is a clear problem. `-o program` must always be together, whether `-I /Users/user/SQLAPI/include` (also always together as one unit) comes before or after that doesn't matter.